# How to sandbox a rails application so that dependencies are installed locally without having to re-run bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sandbox

I'm trying to sandbox a rails application so that i can port it over to other machines without having to re-bundle. Is there a way for rails to pull in dependencies locally to self-sustain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All dependencies are stored in the Gemfile.lock. All gems stored in ruby directory. You can run once bundle install to create Gemfile.lock. Then save Gemefile.lock and pack a directory with gems. After it you can copy your pack to server and deploy you application.

Comment: but if you move directory to a different environment, say docker, and say you don't have internet, you wouldn't be able to bundle install.

Comment: you don't need to run bundle install if have Gemfile.lock and have same ruby version and all gems according to Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Also look at `bundle package` and `bundle install --local` commands. Maybe that what you need.

Comment: is there a way you can specify --local for certain gems?

Comment: If you use in Gemfile gem "gem name", path: "/local/path". Then your gem will be installed from local machine

Comment: gem install - - local /path/to/file. gem

Comment: Also, bundle install command search gems locally before downloading.